# PostSharp - Seems like debug symbols are not updated

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, postsharp

I have a Web Api (.net4.5) project with PostSharp(v3.1.52) added. When I try  debug the source code, the single step (F10) doesn't jump to the next code line. It jumps to random lines below. If I put breakpoints on the lines it has skipped it says no symbols have been loaded.

I also cannot inspect some symbols - ie I get dreaded error "Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away." 
This usually is a sign I'm not running in debug mode.

Things I have tried...

1. check the project is running in Debug mode - can confirm this by writing logs inside #if Debug.
2. Set SkipPostSharp = True
3. Uncheck "Optimize code" in the Project Build settings - FYI is I do this no debug symbols even load.
4. Installed lastest VS2017 updates (15.7.2)
5. Cleaned the solution
6. Restart machine
7. Last resort, I have changed .net versions and also tried updating PostSharp to later nuget version, alas no changes.

I'm not entirely sure that PostSharp is the issue, not ruling it out though.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's been my experience that stack corruption causes the execution pointer to jump around sometimes randomly after calling a method. Maybe it would be helpful for you to modify your post and add a code example.

Comment: Please make sure you have the latest PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio installed. (https://www.postsharp.net/download) If this in combination with the latest PostSharp NuGet packages still doesn't work, please provide a reproduction so we can have a closer look.

Comment: @Cwisking, Do you mean that you couldn't step Into the specific Nuget Package?Which symbols were not loaded in your side? You could view the debug Modules window, could you get the pdb files in your project output path?